# Sources for California roads data

Tags: data, network, road

I need a California roads network suitable for building a network dataset and routing to 120 locations. It needs to at least cover the Northern half of California. 2010 Census roads need alot of cleanup or I would try using those. Any ideas for places to start?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you seeking Commercial Data sets (Navteq, TeleAtlas) or are you looking for 'free' Open Access datasets?

Comment: free open access data if possible

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). If quality is good enough for your purpose.